# How to get attributeset value as "@color/desktop_purple"

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have two apks, such as packageA, packageB;
Meanwhile I create a custom-view named HomeSuite
Here is my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/page_linearlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/hometopfragment_layout_margintop"
    android:layout_weight="16" >

    <com.my.example.view.HomeSuite
        android:background="@color/desktop_purple"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.my.example.view.HomeSuite
        android:background="@color/desktop_grey"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.my.example.view.HomeSuite
        android:background="@color/desktop_light_green"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the constructor:

```
public HomeSuite(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    int n = attrs.getAttributeCount();
    String name ;
    String value ;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        name = attrs.getAttributeName(i);
        value = attrs.getAttributeValue(i);
    }
    mContext = (Activity) context;
    mPackageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();

}
```

When I get the name="background", and the value="@2131230733", which I'm expecting get "@color/desktop_purple", I'd like to use this value as resource name to reading resource from PackageB.

```
    int id = packageBContext.getResources().getIdentifier(value, "color", packageB);
    return packageBContext.getResources().getColor(id);
```

I need to know the the value "@color/desktop_purple", then I can figure out it's "color" related or "drawable" related, after that I can decide to use getColor(id) or getDrawable(id).

Anyone can help?